# I want to place a button above another UI element programmatically in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to place a button programmatically above a separator but it doesn't show at run time this is my view in story board shown in the picture [image: x]

the separator is UIview I dragged and dropped it in storyboard and linked it to my controller

this is my code
//

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit

class LoginController: UIViewController, FBSDKLoginButtonDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var separator: UIView!
    @IBOutlet var fbLoginButton: UIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        if FBSDKAccessToken.current() != nil {
            // Present the main view because user already logged in
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToHome", sender: self)
        }else{

            loginButtonUI()
        }
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(true)

        loginButtonUI()
    }

    private func loginButtonUI(){

        let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
        loginButton.delegate = self
        // Optional: Place the button in the center of your view.
        loginButton.center = view.center
        view.addSubview(loginButton)
    }

    func loginButton(_ loginButton: FBSDKLoginButton!, didCompleteWith result: FBSDKLoginManagerLoginResult!, error: Error!) {

        // fb login code

    }


}
```

but the button doesn't show at run time why?

Comment: Do not show us code with no context. We have no idea whether the code you showed ever even runs.

Comment: when I comment the uncommented lines and uncomment the commented lines the code works and I have a facebook login button in the login view

Comment: @loaymansour Use breakpoint in `loginButtonUI` method and check whether this method is called

Answer (score 1):

you need to activate your constraints, and make sure you added correctly

```
let loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton()
    loginButton.delegate = self

    view.addSubview(loginButton)
    loginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    loginButton.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separatorView.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    loginButton.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: separatorView.topAnchor, constant: 20).isActive = true
    loginButton.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
    loginButton.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 40).isActive = true
```

Comment: sorry about that I forget to add the following line

`loginButton.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`

I have edited my answer please check it

Comment: @omartarek32 Even if no constraints are added the button should show in default size. If the button doesn't show OP has problem somewhere else

Comment: for FBSDKLoginButton I think it has default width and height so, you may do not need to add constraint for width and height, but it will not appear anyway if you do not add the bottom and center constraint, you MUST add constraint to control your button position

Comment: thanks omar I tried something else and it worked thank you

Comment: your are welcome, you can also share the answer here to help the other in the future